# publishing .tar.gz with npm publish

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I am using `npm publish` to publish a package to artifactory. I am able to pulish the package to artifactory with .tgz extension using the 'npm publish' command but I was wondering if there was a way I can publish the package with .tar.gz extension? I understand they are basically the same thing but all of our files on artifactory are tar.gz so for convention's sake I'd like to change the extension if possible.